# What is the difference between MOD16A2 and MOD16A2GF products?

Tags: modis

I want to use the evapotranspiration product, which one will be the suitable to show net evapotranspiration on large and arid area? Thanks

Comment: The difference of MOD16A2GF as compared to MOD16A2 is described here: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod16a2gfv006/